# How to run prettier in browser to format code? e.g. inside ReactJs app

Tags: reactjs, browser, prettier

I have code editor (CodeMirror v6) inside my ReactJS app and want to format code post edit with prettier. How to run prettier in browser?

Looking for something like:

`prettier.format(code)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what found out after some test and fails:

There is Standalone package of prettier which does not require anything from NodeJs.

It has some limitations:

> It only formats the code and has no support for config files, ignore files, CLI usage, or automatic loading of plugins.
> https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html

Also inside `prettier.format` selected plugins and parser must be set manually.

Inside index.html, add standalone prettier + babel parser, which is enough to run prettier from a global variable:

```js
// JS script, should be run after <script> tags load
const formatted = prettier.format("console.log( 'ok')", {
  parser: "babel",
  plugins: prettierPlugins,
});
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.6.2/standalone.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.6.2/parser-babel.js"></script>
```

[image]

`prettierPlugins` was also exposed from these script tags, it is not my custom code.

[image]
[image]